# Rewrite URL redirect via A-Record

Tags: url, redirect, nginx

I have a wordpress running on NGINX and my configuration is very common.

I am using 1.com on it and have set the A-Record for 2.com to the servers IP, where 1.com is running on.

When I hit 2.com, it shows up 1.com, but remains 2.com in the URL.

How can I setup a redirect to 2.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define server block for `2.com`

Comment: really necessary? Is there not way to intercept the call for the domain?

Comment: There is. It's called «new server block». It's the only right way

Comment: works like a charm. thanks for pointing to the right direction. You may post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting a domain in NGINX:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;

        server_name xxx.de;
        return 301 $scheme://yyy.de$request_uri;
}
```